# Node.js / Javascript multiple recursive promise to return at view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, recursion, promise

I currently have an algorithm with multiple recursive calls from which I expect everyone to return in order to consolidate my result

The problem is that there are so many recursive calls that I no longer see how to return my consolidated result

I tried to make a promise.all at the end of each promise by checking the number of promises by the number of results, but I got a result indicating that I was making several http responses

With this version, I return the result before all my promises are executed or added to my promise list.

```
var https = require('https');
var moment = require('moment');

app.get('/detail/:issue', function (req, res) {

    var promises = [];
    var jsonResult = {
        total: {
            daysSpent: 0,
            daysEstimated: 0,
            daysRemaining: 0,
            cost: 0
        },
        issues: {}
    };

    var getIssue = function (key) {

        /**
         * Récupération des imputations par projet.
         */
        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve) {

            var options = Object.assign({}, app.locals.data.jira);
            options.path = "/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}"
                .replace('{issueKey}', key);

            https.request(options, (resp) => {
                let body = '';
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', () => {

                    var issue = JSON.parse(body);

                    if (issue.fields.issuetype.name == 'Epic') {
                        getEpic(issue.key);
                    } else {

                        jsonResult.issues[issue.key] = {
                            key: issue.key,
                            numberTicket: issue.fields.customfield_10267 === null ? "-" : issue.fields.customfield_10267,
                            icon: issue.fields.issuetype.iconUrl,
                            name: issue.fields.summary,
                            status: issue.fields.status.name,
                            daysEstimated: issue.fields.issuetype.subtask ? (((issue.fields.timeoriginalestimate || 0) / 3600) / 7) : ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7),
                            daysRemaining: issue.fields.issuetype.subtask ? (((issue.fields.timeoriginalestimate || 0) / 3600) / 7) : ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7),
                            hoursSpent: 0,
                            daysSpent: 0,
                            cost: 0,
                            parent: issue.fields.parent === undefined ? issue.key : issue.fields.parent.key,
                            detail: {},
                            subtask: issue.fields.issuetype.subtask,
                            worklog: issue.fields.worklog.total != 0
                        }

                        jsonResult.total.daysEstimated += ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7);
                        jsonResult.total.daysRemaining += ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7);

                        if (issue.fields.subtasks != false) {
                            for (let e in issue.fields.subtasks) {
                                e = issue.fields.subtasks[e];
                                getIssue(e.key);
                            };
                        }

                        if (issue.fields.worklog.total != 0) {
                            getWorklog(issue.key);
                        }
                    }

                    resolve();

                });
            }).on("error", (e) => {
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            }).end();
        }));

    }

    var getEpic = function (key) {

        /**
         * Récupération des imputations par projet.
         */
        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve) {

            var postData = JSON.stringify({
                "jql": "'Epic link' = {issueKey}"
                    .replace('{issueKey}', key),
                "maxResults": -1,
                "fields": [
                    "issuekey"
                ]
            });

            var options = Object.assign({}, app.locals.data.jira);
            options.path = "/jira/rest/api/2/search";
            options.method = 'POST';
            options.headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(postData)
            };

            var req = https.request(options, (resp) => {
                let body = '';
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', () => {

                    var issues = JSON.parse(body).issues;

                    for (let issue in JSON.parse(body).issues) {
                        issue = issues[issue];
                        getIssue(issue.key);
                    };

                    resolve();

                });
            }).on("error", (e) => {
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            });

            req.write(postData);
            req.end();
        }));

    }

    var getWorklog = function (key) {

        /**
         * Récupération des imputations par projet.
         */
        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve) {

            var options = Object.assign({}, app.locals.data.jira);
            options.path = "/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}/worklog"
                .replace('{issueKey}', key);

            https.request(options, (resp) => {
                let body = '';
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', () => {

                    var worklogs = JSON.parse(body).worklogs;

                    for (let e in worklogs) {

                        e = worklogs[e];

                        if (jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key] == undefined) {
                            jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key] = {
                                name: e.author.displayName,
                                hoursSpent: 0,
                                daysSpent: 0,
                                cost: 0
                            }
                        }

                        jsonResult.issues[key].hoursSpent += e.timeSpentSeconds / 3600;
                        jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key].hoursSpent += e.timeSpentSeconds / 3600;

                        if (app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")] !== undefined && app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")][e.author.emailAddress] !== undefined) {

                            var time = (e.timeSpentSeconds / 3600) / app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")][e.author.emailAddress].modality;
                            var cost = time * app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")][e.author.emailAddress].scr;

                            jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key].daysSpent += time;
                            jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key].cost += cost;

                            jsonResult.issues[key].daysSpent += time;
                            jsonResult.issues[key].cost += cost;
                            jsonResult.issues[key].daysRemaining -= time;

                    };

                    resolve();

                });
            }).on("error", (e) => {
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            }).end();

        }));

    }

    getIssue(req.params.issue);

    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        res.json(jsonResult);
    });

});
```

Comment: recursion can be a great technique for certain problems; in this case, it is adding too much cognitive overhead (meaning its difficult to trace the program execution).  Have you tried an iterative approach?  What condition(s) terminate the recursion?  It also would be useful to split all these functions into individual files.

Comment: I suggest you use `async/await` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) instead of promises. This will allow you to write  function calls as if they were synchronous functions

Comment: It is not possible to do iteratively since I do not know in advance the number of elements that will have to be treated. I process data up to 3 hierarchical levels, of which the 2nd level can have a number X of children. I will try again the await/async solution, it's an approach I thought I might be able to do but nodeJS told me I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my problem !

```
var https = require('https');
var moment = require('moment');

app.get('/detail/:issue', function (req, res) {

    var jsonResult = {
        total: {
            daysSpent: 0,
            daysEstimated: 0,
            daysRemaining: 0,
            cost: 0
        },
        issues: {}
    };

    var getIssue = function (key) {

        /**
         * Récupération des imputations par projet.
         */
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {

            var options = Object.assign({}, app.locals.data.jira);
            options.path = "/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}"
                .replace('{issueKey}', key);

            https.request(options, (resp) => {
                let body = '';
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', () => {

                    var promises = [];
                    var issue = JSON.parse(body);

                    if (issue.fields.issuetype.name == 'Epic') {
                        promises.push(getEpic(issue.key));
                    } else {

                        jsonResult.issues[issue.key] = {
                            key: issue.key,
                            numberTicket: issue.fields.customfield_10267 === null ? "-" : issue.fields.customfield_10267,
                            icon: issue.fields.issuetype.iconUrl,
                            name: issue.fields.summary,
                            status: issue.fields.status.name,
                            daysEstimated: issue.fields.issuetype.subtask ? (((issue.fields.timeoriginalestimate || 0) / 3600) / 7) : ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7),
                            daysRemaining: issue.fields.issuetype.subtask ? (((issue.fields.timeoriginalestimate || 0) / 3600) / 7) : ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7),
                            hoursSpent: 0,
                            daysSpent: 0,
                            cost: 0,
                            parent: issue.fields.parent === undefined ? issue.key : issue.fields.parent.key,
                            detail: {},
                            subtask: issue.fields.issuetype.subtask,
                            worklog: issue.fields.worklog.total != 0
                        }

                        jsonResult.total.daysEstimated += ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7);
                        jsonResult.total.daysRemaining += ((issue.fields.customfield_11901 || 0) / 7);

                        if (issue.fields.worklog.total != 0) {
                            promises.push(getWorklog(issue.key));
                        }

                        if (issue.fields.subtasks != false) {
                            for (let e in issue.fields.subtasks) {
                                e = issue.fields.subtasks[e];
                                promises.push(getIssue(e.key));
                            };
                        }
                    }

                    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
                        resolve();
                    });

                });
            }).on("error", (e) => {
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            }).end();

        });
    }

    var getEpic = function (key) {

        /**
         * Récupération des imputations par projet.
         */
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {

            var postData = JSON.stringify({
                "jql": "'Epic link' = {issueKey}"
                    .replace('{issueKey}', key),
                "maxResults": -1,
                "fields": [
                    "issuekey"
                ]
            });

            var options = Object.assign({}, app.locals.data.jira);
            options.path = "/jira/rest/api/2/search";
            options.method = 'POST';
            options.headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(postData)
            };

            var req = https.request(options, (resp) => {
                let body = '';
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', () => {

                    var promises = [];
                    var issues = JSON.parse(body).issues;

                    for (let issue in JSON.parse(body).issues) {
                        issue = issues[issue];
                        promises.push(getIssue(issue.key));
                    };

                    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
                        resolve();
                    });

                });
            }).on("error", (e) => {
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            });

            req.write(postData);
            req.end();

        });
    }

    var getWorklog = function (key) {

        /**
         * Récupération des imputations par projet.
         */
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {

            var options = Object.assign({}, app.locals.data.jira);
            options.path = "/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}/worklog"
                .replace('{issueKey}', key);

            https.request(options, (resp) => {
                let body = '';
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', () => {

                    var worklogs = JSON.parse(body).worklogs;

                    for (let e in worklogs) {

                        e = worklogs[e];

                        if (jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key] == undefined) {
                            jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key] = {
                                name: e.author.displayName,
                                hoursSpent: 0,
                                daysSpent: 0,
                                cost: 0
                            }
                        }

                        jsonResult.issues[key].hoursSpent += e.timeSpentSeconds / 3600;
                        jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key].hoursSpent += e.timeSpentSeconds / 3600;

                        if (app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")] !== undefined && app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")][e.author.emailAddress] !== undefined) {

                            var time = (e.timeSpentSeconds / 3600) / app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")][e.author.emailAddress].modality;
                            var cost = time * app.locals.data.scr[moment(e.started).format("Y")][e.author.emailAddress].scr;

                            jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key].daysSpent += time;
                            jsonResult.issues[key].detail[e.author.key].cost += cost;

                            jsonResult.issues[key].daysSpent += time;
                            jsonResult.issues[key].cost += cost;
                            jsonResult.issues[key].daysRemaining -= time;

                            if (jsonResult.issues[key].subtask) {
                                jsonResult.issues[jsonResult.issues[key].parent].hoursSpent += e.timeSpentSeconds / 3600;
                                jsonResult.issues[jsonResult.issues[key].parent].daysSpent += time;
                                jsonResult.issues[jsonResult.issues[key].parent].cost += cost;
                                jsonResult.issues[jsonResult.issues[key].parent].daysRemaining -= time;
                            }

                            jsonResult.total.daysSpent += time;
                            jsonResult.total.cost += cost;
                            jsonResult.total.daysRemaining -= time;
                        }
                    };

                    resolve();

                });
            }).on("error", (e) => {
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            }).end();

        });

    }

    getIssue(req.params.issue).then(function () {
        res.json(jsonResult);
    });

});
```

each method waits for all its sub-methods to end in order to conclude